# How to combine the two commands into one with pipe?

Tags: bash, openssl, tar

Package directroy `$HOME/Desktop/bill` into  `/tmp/bill.tar` and encrypt it with key into `/tmp/bill.asc`.

```
 key="xxxxxxxx"
 tar -zcP  $HOME/Desktop/bill  -f  /tmp/bill.tar
 openssl enc -des3 -a -salt  -in  /tmp/bill.tar  -k ${key} -out /tmp/bill.asc
```

I want to combine tar and openssl as one whole command with pipe.

> tar -zcP  $HOME/Desktop/bill  -f  | openssl enc -des3 -a -salt  -in   -k ${key} -out /tmp/bill.asc

It can't work,how to fix it?

Comment: Does `tar -zcP  $HOME/Desktop/bill  -f  /tmp/bill.tar | openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -k ${key} -out /tmp/bill.asc` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `-f` parameter,remove `-in` parameter in `Bsquare`'s post.

```
tar -zcP $HOME/Desktop/bill |openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -k ${key} -out /tmp/bill.asc
```

With  `-f` parameter,same as John Law say.

```
tar -zcP $HOME/Desktop/bill -f /tmp/bill.tar | openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -k ${key} -out /tmp/bill.asc
```